# The type already contains a definition for ' '

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a contact class represent individual contacts that would appear in my contact manager application but I keep getting the error The type 'cpsc1012_advanced_A.Contact' already contains a definition for 'ContactTypes'.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
class Contact
{
    //private member variables
    private String _firstName;
    private String _lastName;
    private Type _contactTypes;
    private String _phoneNumber;
    private String _emailAddress;




    //Public constructor that takes five arguments
    public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, Type contactTypes, String phoneNumber, String emailAddress)
    {
        //Call the appropriate setter (e.g. FirstName) to set the member variable value
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        ContactTypes = contactTypes;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        EmailAddress = emailAddress;

    }


    /*********************************************************************
     * Public accessors used to get and set private member variable values
     *********************************************************************/
    //Public  ContactTypes accessor
    public Type ContactTypes
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _contactTypes;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
                throw new Exception("ContactType must have a value");
            else
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _lastName = value;
        }
    }
    enum ContactTypes { Family, Friend, Professional }
    //Public FirstName accessor: Pascal casing
    public String GetFirstName
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
                throw new Exception("First name must have a value");
            else
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _firstName = value;
        }
    }

    //Public LastName accessor: Pascal casing
    public String GetLastName
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
                throw new Exception("Last name must have a value");
            else
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _lastName = value;
        }
    }



    //Public PhoneNumber accessor
    public String GetPhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(value, @"/d{3}-/d{3}-/d{4}");
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
                throw new Exception("PhoneNumber must have a value");
            else
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _lastName = value;
        }
    }



    //Public Email accessor
    public String GetEmailAddress
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _emailAddress;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
                throw new Exception("EmailAddress must have a value");
            else
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _emailAddress = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line `enum ContactTypes { Family, Friend, Professional }`

To
`enum ContactTypesEnum { Family, Friend, Professional }`